# Routing traffic on different instances on Aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two instances and one domain (domain.com)

1. One where there is a java website
2. Other where there is a wp website

Right now, domain.com opens up a java website and everything works fine.

I want to open up a wordPress website on domain.com/a

The traffic is routed using nginx.

WordPress handles all the URL's once the domain is mapped. What are the standard procedures to handle this type of query?

Comment: I had a quick google, is nginx location routing what you're trying to do here?

Comment: why can not you open it via sub domain a.domain.com ?

Comment: Hey Kush. We thought of it in the first place. But the client doesn't want a subdomain. He wants to keep the domain.com url structure

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use the `proxy_pass` directive:

```
location /a {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
}
```

For more information, take a look at the following links:

1. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/
2. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching

Comment: Hey Dima, Thanks. But routing is working fine. But once the traffic is brought to the new domain.com/a the url structure doesn't remain intact. All the requests are sent to the original domain.com. How do we avoid this?

Comment: Well, you have to change all URL's on your WP website. I don't have much experience with WP, but I suggest that `Permalinks` can help (https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).